# Show facebook, twitter status updates in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, social-networking

in my webpage, I want to show facebook and twitter status updates of my account, as one. Means show statuses from twitter and fb date wise. As shown below:

```
T: twitter status update 1
T: twitter status update 2
F: Facebook status update 3
T: twitter status update 4
F: Facebook status update 5
```

I am using wordpress for my website, is there any such plugin in wordpress? or any code using which I can do it manually in php?

Please check and advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is php code for twitter update/status.

```
    $body = array(
        'status'=>'YOURMESSAGE'
    );
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
    $oauth_access_token = "YOURVALUE";
    $oauth_access_token_secret = "YOURVALUE";
    $consumer_key = "YOURVALUE";
    $consumer_secret = "YOURVALUE";

    $oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce' => time(),
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_version' => '1.0');

    $base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'POST', $oauth);
    $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
    $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
    $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
    $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $json = curl_exec($feed);
    curl_close($feed);

    $result_data = json_decode($json);

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}
```

`